# How to retain <noscript> tag in HTML output when added in a Views Fields?

Tags: 7, views

I need to re-write some fields in my Views to output certain format for my `<img>` tag. Since the new format that needs to be written isn't actually accessible, I would need to include `<noscript>` tag for the original `<img>` tag.

#### Example

**Accessible, original format**

```
<img src="/images/myimage.jpg">
```

**Non-Accessible, new format**

```
<img src="/images/placeholder.jpg" data-original="/images/myimage.jpg">
<noscript><img src="/images/myimage.jpg"</noscript>
```

### Question

How to make it so that the `<noscript>` tag is retained and not stripped?

Please kindly share your detailed solutions in a way that a Drupal beginner like me can understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module for the `<noscript>` tag to be retained. Even so, had to do some workaround to make it work >.<